# Cannot set Java 8 on Windows 7

Tags: java

I just downloaded and installed Java 8 on Windows 8 (64 bit). I have updated the classpath, java home environment variables to point to the new version. But when I try to use the lambda expression on a code from Intellij (13.0.2) , it says Lambda not supported at this language level.
  Also when I run this from command prompt:  java -version
it says the version is 7.
Can someone please help me setting the Java 8 as default on my system?

Thanks!

Comment: try doing `whereis java`, I think the location you get is of java7, set the path of java to java 8 in .bashrc, and do `bash` and check .. 
I think the question is related to linux

Comment: Please provide (from a command window) the output from `echo %PATH%`, `echo %CLASSPATH%` and `echo %JAVA_HOME%`

Comment: @progrrammer the op said he is using `windows 8 64 bit`. How can his question be related to `linux`?

Comment: @DavidPostill                                                                          echo %CLASSPATH%
;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\lib;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\BIN    

echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin

Comment: @user1318369: CLASSPATH and JAVA_HOME are irrelevant. What matters is the PATH. That's where Windows looks for executables. And java.exe is an executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to use `java -version` in a command prompt and have Java 8 as the result, the Java 8's `bin` directory must be in the PATH environment variable, before the other directories where java.exe exists (so, for example, at the very beginning of the PATH.

In IntelliJ IDEA, you have to open File - Project structure and

- under *SDKs*, make sure the 1.8 SDK is selected and not 1.7. If 1.8 isn't listed, then click the *+* icon at the top and add it
- under *Project*, make sure the project SDK is 1.8, and the project language level is 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change it in the Project structure menu under :
File > Project structure > Modules
and then source tab

[image]